# Assign a custom image to product created programmatically-Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

once guest user click on button "**add to cart1**" , we are doing below things :

1] we are creating simple product programatically

2] we are assigning custom image to that product.

3] Display one more pop-up to Login to site by click on "login" button

once user click on "login button , we are doing below things :

1] we are creating simple product programmatically

2] we are not assigning a custom image to that product.

but here we need to assign custom image to that product.

```
public function thisSimpleProductAndRedirectAction()
    {
        $originalProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        // $productNameArray = explode(" - ",$this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
        // $originalProductId = $productNameArray[0];
        $newImagePath      = $this->getRequest()->getParam("image");
        $originalProduct   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($originalProductId);

        if ($product = $this->_createProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath)) {
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode("custom image saving"));
        }
        else{
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode("custom image not saving"));
        }

    }

 protected function _thisImage($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        // code for Guest
        Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);    
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');



        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $login ="";
        $productId ="";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }
            // echo $login['product_id'];die;
            // if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    if(isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login!="")){
                        $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                        $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                            '_secure' => true
                        ));
                        $result['success']  = true;
                        $customerId         = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    }
                    else{
                        $customerId = "";
                    }

                    // code for guest end        

                    $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());

                    // add images

                    $images = array(
                        'thumbnail' => 'image.png', // displaying under cart page

                        'image' => 'image.png' // displaying under my design
                    );

                    foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
                        if ($newImagePath != "") {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
                            $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
                        } else {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
                            $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
                        }
                        //echo $path."<br>";
                        if (file_exists($path)) {
                            try {
                                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                            }
                            catch (Exception $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
                        }
                    }                  

                    $emailimage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');

                    if ($doSave)
                        $product->save();                  

                    return $product;

                    // code for guest

                }
                catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $result['error'] = $message;
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result = "ERROR :".$e->getMesage();

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        // code for guest end
    }
```

updated the question = >

add to cart1 code is as below :

```
<button onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo 

Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);" 

 id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >Add to cart1</button>
```

> update 2 :

once we click on `add to cart1` , it redirect to [link5](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect/id/19966/image/1639042285.png/) with image parameter

and when we click on  `login` , it redirect to [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect/id/19966/) without image param , so only image not creating for login.....

Comment: Once again, you've posted code and what you "expect" to happen.  What is __actually__ happening?  Are you getting any errors?  Is there anything in your logs?  Have you tried logging the `$path` variable to see what the full path is?  Do you have the ability to step-through your code with a debugger like PHPStorm with Remote Debug?

Comment: @Brett i dont see any errors in logs. sorry  i dont have any debuggers , please guide me how to ` loggin the $path variable to see what the full path is` ?

Comment: `Mage::log("File Path: " . $path, Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'debug.log');` Add that line where you have `//echo $path."<br>";` Then run your code and look in `var/log/debug.log` to see what the path is set as.

Comment: @Brett when we click on `addtocart1` button, its showing image path as in debug.log file as `media/custom_product_preview/quote/514075431.png` , but when i click on `login` button, it showing image path as `media/example/amasty/image.png`

Comment: So it seems that your `$newImagePath` isn't persisting after logging in or you're not saving the new image path in your session and retrieving it properly after login.  I don't see a `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNewImagePath($newImagePath);`, so how are you saving the `$newImagePath` to be read back AFTER they log in?

Comment: @Brett i added your code `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNewImagePath($new‌​ImagePath);` above line : `foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName)` , if i am wrong please guide me in correct way.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're not persisting the `$newImagePath` value from before login to after login (or before redirect to after redirect).  This value needs to be kept somewhere (like the session) so ensure you can use it later.

So I would probably do the following:

```
foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
    if ($newImagePath != "") {
         $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
         $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
    } else {
         $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
         $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
    }

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        try {
            if ($imageType == 'image' && $newImagePath) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNewImagePath($path);
            }
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
    }
}
```

Then after they've logged in and you're doing whatever you need to do, you can retrieve the full new image path using:

```
$newImagePath = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNewImagePath();
```

It's unclear how you use the `$newImagePath` after they've logged in, so I can't help much more than for you to retrieve the value from the session after they've logged in (the above line of code).

Comment: still the same, please let me if you want to know any other details......

Comment: onclick login button, we are not saving custom images in server, is that causing the issue as in link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171175/executing-js-function-onclick-button-which-is-present-inside-form

Comment: If you're not saving the data posted before you redirect them, you'll lose the file upon redirect.  PHP cleans up temporary uploaded files unless you move them with `move_uploaded_file` (or some other mechanism).  So if you're not saving the file before redirecting them, that's an issue.

Comment: yes, once we click on `button `add to cart1/create`, we are saving custom image in server and displaying pop up , in pop up once user enter email, pw, click on login, we are creating only product, we are not creating any custom image in server, so to solve this issue, i posted a question     , when you get free time please check link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171175/executing-js-function-onclick-button-which-is-present-inside-form

Answer (score 0):

Please do refer this -

> https://www.hummingbirduk.com/add-images-to-products-programmatically-in-magento/

Hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace this code :

```
if ($newImagePath != "") 
{
     $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
     $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
} 
else 
{
      $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
      $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
}
```

with this :

```
 $path = '';
if ($newImagePath != "") 
    {
         $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
         $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
    } 
    else 
    {
          $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
          $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
    }
```

Comment: its not working , can you re any other idea ?

Comment: have you debug code, you get proper value $path ?

Comment: This code makes no difference.  `$path` would be initialized no matter if `$newImagePath` is empty or not, so adding `$path = '';` won't have any effect.

Comment: but in above code, very next to this code it check this if (file_exists($path)) So it is usefull to check that properly pathis assign or not.