# Executing JS function onclick button which is present inside form

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, image, forms, third-party-module

We have button "*`create`*" and `onclick` "*`Create`*" button, it will create *`product programmatically`* and assign *`custom image`* to that product.

**app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme3/template/aitcg - js_styles1.phtml**

```
<script>

var Aitcg_View_Abstract = Class.create(
{

_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div>' +
                '<button  onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();"  id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}">create</button>' +
                '<button>reset</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

initObservers: function() 
      { 
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {  
           $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.createDesignBut.bindAsEventListener(this));           
         } 
       }, 

createDesignBut: function(event) 
        { 
          Event.stop(event); 
          this.option.apply(); 
        },     
}); 

</script>
```

we are trying to do the same [ create product programtically and assign custom image ] , once we submit form by clicking "login button".
here we are creating product sucessfully, but `custom image` is not saving in server, to save custom image in server onclick "*login*" button, we are using same function that "create" button is using as below code :

**app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme3/template/productlike - index.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect', 
array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'), 
'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())) ?>" id="ajaxlogin-login-form">

// code for email id and password //

<button onclick="initObservers()" type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" 
name="send" id="send2"><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span>
</button>

</form>
```

but still custom image is not saving in server onclick "login" button.

Is this right way ?

updated code - >

```
                    $images = array(
                        'thumbnail' => 'image.png', // displaying under cart 
                        //'small_image' => 'image.png',
                        'image' => 'image.png' // displaying under my design
                    );

                    foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
                        if ($newImagePath != "") {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
                            $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
                        } else {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
                            $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
                        }
```

Comment: Where is the image code?

Comment: @urfusion updated the question with image code ....can you check and do something pls......